# Python nested scopes with dynamic features

Tags: python, name-binding

Need help with understanding the following sentence from [PEP 227](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0227/) and the [Python Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/executionmodel.html#interaction-with-dynamic-features)

> If a variable is referenced in an enclosed scope, it is an error to
>   delete the name.  The compiler will raise a SyntaxError for 'del
>   name'.

Lack of examples caused I couldn't reproduce an error at compile time, so an explanation with examples is highly desirable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following raises the execption:

```
def foo():
    spam = 'eggs'
    def bar():
        print spam
    del spam
```

because the `spam` variable is being used in the enclosed scope of `bar`:

```
>>> def foo():
...     spam = 'eggs'
...     def bar():
...         print spam
...     del spam
... 
SyntaxError: can not delete variable 'spam' referenced in nested scope
```

Python detects that `spam` is being referenced in `bar` but does not assign anything to that variable, so it looks it up in the surrounding scope of `foo`. It *is* assigned there, making the `del spam` statement a syntax error.

This limitation was removed in Python 3.2; you are now responsible for not deleting nested variables yourself; you'll get a runtime error (`NameError`) instead:

```
>>> def foo():
...     spam = 'eggs'
...     def bar():
...         print(spam)
...     del spam
...     bar()
... 
>>> foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in foo
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in bar
NameError: free variable 'spam' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope
```

Answer (score 5):

An example can be this one:

```
>>> def outer():
...     x = 0
...     y = (x for i in range(10))
...     del x
... 
SyntaxError: can not delete variable 'x' referenced in nested scope
```

Basically it means you can't delete variables that are used in inner blocks(in that case the genexp).

Note that this apply for python <= 2.7.x and python < 3.2.
In python3.2 it's it does not raise syntax error:

```
>>> def outer():
...     x = 0
...     y = (x for i in range(10))
...     del x
... 
>>>
```

See [this](http://bugs.python.org/issue4617) link for the whole story of the change.

I think the python3.2 semanthics is more correct because if you write the same code outside a function it works:

```
#python2.7
>>> x = 0
>>> y = (x for i in range(10))
>>> del x
>>> y.next()     #this is what I'd expect: NameError at Runtime
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <genexpr>
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
```

While putting the same code into a function, not only changes exception but the error is at compile time.