# Doubts about python variable scope

Tags: python, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Short Description of Python Scoping Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules)

I wrote two simple functions:

```
# coding: utf-8
def test():
    var = 1 
    def print_var():
        print var 
    print_var()
    print var 

test()
# 1
# 1
def test1():
    var = 2 
    def print_var():
        print var 
        var = 3 
    print_var()
    print var 

test1()
# raise Exception
```

In comparison, `test1()` assigns value after `print var`, then raise an Exception: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'var' referenced before assignment`, I think the moment I call inner `print var`, var has a value of 2, am I wrong?

Comment: See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them

Comment: @HansThen: No, a `global` declaration would not help here, as `var` is a function-scope variable. In python 3 you'd use `nonlocal` but in python 2 (as used here) there is no way you can do what the OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're incorrect here.  Function definition introduces a new scope.

```
# coding: utf-8
def test():
    var = 1 
    def print_var():
        print var    <--- var is not in local scope, the var from outer scope gets used
    print_var()
    print var 

test()
# 1
# 1
def test1():
    var = 2 
    def print_var():
        print var     <---- var is in local scope, but not defined yet, ouch
        var = 3 
    print_var()
    print var 

test1()
# raise Exception
```

Comment: Hang on, I thought python did not look ahead when executing. How does python know that `var` is *going* to be a local variable in the second `print_var` function?

Comment: So when python parses the function it saves a list of the names of all variables that are assigned to within. Then at call time it sees that `var` is in this list, and complains since it's not defined yet. Is this local variable list accessible?

Comment: @lazyr: Exactly; variables are bound to a scope at compile time. Assignment is a storing operation, and binds that variable to the local scope *unless marked global*. If there is no assignment, the variable is 'free' and looked up in surrounding scopes, but this is bound *as well* to that specific scope. See [Python nested scopes with dynamic features](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338713/12338782#12338782) for example.

Comment: @Martijn Can I access the scope of a function and see what its local variables are called?

Comment: @wim I meant from outside the function. We've established such a list exists, but where is it?

Comment: @lazyr: Yes, see http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html, `afunction.func_code.co_varnames` are local variables. `co_freevars` and `co_cellvars` are interesting in this respect; they are variables taken from the surrounding scope (non-global) and variables referred to by nested functions, respectively.

Comment: @wim Right. Martijn answered my question, and I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/370380/566644) answer that details the lexing process that raises UnboundLocalError.