# Sending many variables through functions

Tags: python, if-statement, int

I don't know the rules to defining a var.
Why doesn't this work?
Is there a way that I can send many variables from one function to another or do I need to re-define the variables in each function to make them last?

```
def first():
  great = 1
  print(great)
  second()

def second(great):
  # Do I need to re-define great here
  if great == 1:
    cool = 3001
  third(great, cool)

def third(great, cool):
  if great > 1:
    print(cool)
  # To make great = 1 here?

first()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python global/local variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091357/python-global-local-variables)

Answer (score 2):

Because `great` is defined within the scope of `first()`, not `second()`. You need to change your functions to:

```
def first():
    great = 1
    # code
    second(great)

def second(great):
    if great == 1:
        # code
```

Answer (score 2):

Look up [globals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python) in Python. This works:

```
def first():
   global great
   great = 1
   print(great)
   second()

def second():
   if great == 1:
     print ("awesome")
   else:
     print("God damn it!")

first()
```

In your original functions, `great` was only in the *local* scope of `first()`; `second()` had no idea what/where `great` was. Making `great` global (i.e. available to other functions) solves your issue.

Edit: The code above *does* work, but perhaps a better way to do things (per the suggestion below), would be like this:

```
great = 1

def first():
    print(great)
    second()

def second():
    if great == 1:
        print("awesome")
    else:
        print("God damn it!")
```

Or an even better way would be to actually *pass* the value of `great` (as a parameter) to each function.

Comment: Your code won't work. You need to define global variable `great` before getting him into the function. `global` doesn't create a variable, but gets a variable from the outer scope.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `great` is defined locally in `first()`.  It doesn't exist in `second()`.  You are testing for equality on a variable that doesn't exist.

Pass the variable from one function to the other...

```
def first():
  great = 1
  print(great)
  second(great)

def second(great):
  if great == 1:
    print ("awesome")
  else:
    print("God damn it!")

first()
```